# Error importing video

Tags: import, video

When I try and import a video:

```
Import["video.avi", {"Frames", {50, 60, 70}}]
```

Or using the original .mp4 codec, which I converted using VLC, gives the same result.

```
Import: Cannot import data as video format.
```

Comment: There isn't really much we can say with the information you provide. Can you play the video in an external player? Where does the video come from? Do you know how it was encoded?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't too sure what information would help. The video plays fine in VLC and other players. 15 fps, I believe it's from a webcam but not sure

Comment: See what elements are available by evaluating `Import["video.avi","Elements"]`.  There should be an ImageList element.  Try to extract your frames with `Import["video.avi","ImageList"][[{50,60,70}]]`.  The same approach may work with the .mp4 file.  Here is a working example of frame extraction:  `Import["ExampleData/bullfinch.mkv", "ImageList"][[{30, 200, 400}]]`